# jflex regular expression any number except zero

Tags: regex, bnf, jflex

I'm new in JFlex and I ran into a problem with regular expression.

I'm trying to write in `.flex` file regex that will recognize any number except zero.

The thing is, when I tried my regex in `.bnf` file everything works fine in *live-preview*, but when i'm trying to use `.flex` generated class - nothing worked.

This is my regex in `.bnf` file that work's well:

```
{
      tokens = [
         NUMBER = 'regexp:^[1-9]\d*'
      ]
}
```

But in `.flex` file this regex is not working:

```
NUMBER = ^[1-9]\d*  // Compile error here. <expression> expected, got '^'
NUMBER = [^[1-9]\d*]  // Compiles, but not working.
NUMBER = \^[1-9]\d*\  // Compiles, but not working.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
NUMBER = [1-9][0-9]*
```

This will match a digit from `1` to `9` and then any zero or more digits.

The `^` start of string anchor seems to be not supported here.